# Add custom column to PNP Search filter web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, sharepoint-search, pnp

I am working on PNP Modern Search v4 web part inside our SharePoint Tenant  from this URL - https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/releases/tag/4.4.1.

I have tried to use search box, search result and search filter web part. All the three web parts works fine except when I tried to add custom column to search filter web part, it is not displaying. The custom columns are working on the search result web part but on the filter web part it's not displaying. Any help will be good!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange :) It will be much eaiser to help you post a screen shot of how the filter webpart is configured. But one guess could be are you sure that there is any data in the search index for that column AND also checj if that property is refinable!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a site column
2. Add that into a content type and use anywhere
3. Go to site collection administration insite settings and choose Search schema.
4. Go to crawled property and select a Refinablestring00 as per available and column type
5. Reindex the site.
6. Now it search filter you can see that column appears with suffix ows_002X_column name